# How to declare environment variable in databricks and read the same in R Notebook?

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oBfW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Flml.png)

I'm trying to read the environmental variable declared at the cluster in the code. Can somebody help me with the syntax or the appropriate way to read it in the code?
The expected output should be the dataframe alert_email should have a column Email where the value abc@xyz.com should be reflected.

Comment: Did you try using widgets? 

%r

dbutils.widgets.text("email","hello@email.com")

Comment: No, I haven't tried this method. As I'm pretty new to this. Can you highlight where should I use this command in the notebook where I'm supposed to use it or in the environmental variable section?

Comment: This is not using the Environment variable, this is using the concept of Widgets. https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html  Please read about the concepts here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm closing this thread as I've found the solution to the question. Posting it here,so that somebody could follow this in future.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyvTQ.png)

Once we declare the enivronmental variable at the cluster level. we can call the variable using the syntax
Sys.getenv(c("Email")) in the script.

This will help to read in the script. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).